# Why am i getting the error in this question?

Tags: appcelerator

```
A=[["saurabh",4],["vimlesh",3324],["ranjit",3434],["rakesh",343]]
for i in range(len(A)-1,0,-1):
    for i in range(i):
        if A[j][1]>A[j+1][1]:
            A[j][1],A[j+1][1]=A[j+1][1],A[j][1]
print(A)
```

Comment: How is this question related to appcelerator?

Answer (score 0):

You get an error, because you didn't define `j` variable anywhere. The solution is:

```py
A = [["saurabh", 4], ["vimlesh", 3324], ["ranjit", 3434], ["rakesh", 343]]
for i in range(len(A) - 1, 0, -1):
    for j in range(i):
        if (A[j][1] > A[j + 1][1]):
            A[j][1], A[j + 1][1] = A[j + 1][1], A[j][1]
print(A)
```